# Catch Outlook event without manifest open?

Tags: outlook-addin, manifest, outlook-web-addins

First of all, I'm not a developer as such, but am asking on behalf of our developers.
We have an add-in for the Outlook calendar, created as a manifest.
Is it possible for the manifest to catch an event, for example like pressing the 'invite' button, without the manifest being open?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Thomas

Comment: to clarify, are you referring to an outlook web addin, with manifest that look similar to this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/manifests  There are events support, for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins, but not for all actions. It would be helpful to know a bit more about the scenario. Would you want to run some code on the event, or expect a pane to open, etc?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like our add-in (created as a manifest) to catch for example if the user clicks on 'Recurrence' or 'Invite' on an appointment. However, without the add-in having to be open. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: This feature isn't currently avaliable. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process. aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions